# Customized column in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Two methods:

```
var books = _myIBookRepository.RetrieveAllBooks();  
var bokexamples = _myIbokexamples Repository.RetrieveAllBookExample();
```

Two database table:

BookExample

- BokExampleID  (primary key)
- BookID (Foreign key)
- OrderDetailID (Foreign key)

Book

- BookID   (primary key)
- KategoryID (Foreign key)
- LanguageID (Foreign key)
- Title

BookID is a foreign key in table BookExample from table Book

If orderdetailID is NULL it means that this specfik bookexample is available in the store

Goal:
Display two column that is "Title" and "stock availiable". "stock availiable" is a customized column that don't exist in the database. "stock available" should contain numbers for instance 2 books of title .... is available.

Problem:
Having problem to find right source code in Linq in order to display these two column.

// Fullmetalboy

Comment: Where does the "stock available" numbers come from? Is it calculated based on a count of books with that title in the table?

Comment: You have to make a logical calculation of data based on table BookExample in order to create a list with bok title and its amount of available books. The title should be displayed once with specfiic amout of available stock. I hope you understood my answer. Please tell if I need to make any complementory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var query = from b in books
            select new
            {
                Title = b.Title,
                StockAvailable = bookexamples.Count(be => 
                        be.BookID == b.BookID && 
                        be.OrderDetailID == null
                    )
            };
```

If I understand your question right, this should be what you're looking for.

Comment: +1, I like this much better and is less presumptious than mine.

Comment: This sourcecode was correct to my question! thanks everybody for your support!

Comment: By the way, I still have a follow up problem from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879940/explicit-problem-with-linq   if you are interrested.

Answer (score 1):

You could use another class that encapsulates your `BookExample` class in a form that you want, e.g:

```
public class BookSummary
{
    public int BookID {get; set; }
    public int BookExampleID {get; set; }
    public bool StockAvailable {get; set; }
    public string Title {get; set; }
}


var books = from b in _myIbokexamples Repository.RetrieveAllBookExample().Include("Book") // I'm assuming that's there, lol
            select new BookSummary
            {
                BookID = b.BookID,
                BookExampleID = b.BookExampleID,
                StockAvailable = b.OrderDetailID == null,
                Title = b.Book.Title
            };
```

Comment: Hi, I forgot to tell you that stock available should use int. "stock available" should contain numbers for instance 2 books of title .... is available.