# Explicit problem with LinQ

Tags: c#, linq

A followup to [this previous question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879159/customized-column-in-linq)

Current code:

```
var query = from b in books
             select new
             {
                 Title = b.Title,
                 StockAvailable = bookexamples.Count(be => 
                         be.BookID == b.BookID && 
                         be.OrderDetailID == null
                     )
             };
```

Goal:
Replace `query` with an `IEnumerable<test>` that should contain strongly-typed data from the LINQ query.

```
public class test
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<int> StockAvailable { get; set; }
}
```

Problem:
Recieve a error message:

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>'`
>   to
>   `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<BokButik1.Models.test>'`.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you
>   missing a cast?)

Question:
How should I solve this problem?

// Fullmetalboy

Comment: Edited to clarify what I think you're trying to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to modify the query to return `test` objects (currently, it is returning anomynous objects).

```
var query = from b in books
            select new test()
            {
                Title = b.Title,
                StockAvailable = bookexamples.Count(be => 
                        be.BookID == b.BookID && 
                        be.OrderDetailID == null
                    )
            };
```

You'll need to adjust `StockAvailable` to represent an `int` as `Count` returns an int.

Also, note, that class names in C# are written with a capital letter at the beginning.

Comment: Class names are written with a capital letter in C# by *convention* not by *rule*. There's nothing forcing you to do it that way, but still good advice.

Comment: @FullmetalBoy and @Femaref: Having written the code in the original answer, I agree with this modification given your new requirements. It's certainly what I'd do. +1.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help!
Is there a book or a website there I can read more about c#'s rule of thumb for instance "Class names are written with a capital letter in C#"?